# Content of an XML File with $http not available outside the .succes() context

Tags: angularjs

I have a service `xmlService` which uses the $http service to read an XML-File. Everything is working fine, but when I use my `xmlService` in one of my controllers it returns an empty object, although the $http.get() is successfull. I have no idea whats the problem.

**Update**:
I understood that the $http-call is asyncronous thus I have to use the $q service. I'm not sure if I understood the $q API correctly because my updated code doesn't work either. I also read an tutorial like this one: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2612-using-the-http-service-in-angularjs-to-make-ajax-requests.htm - But I can't find the mistake, because I probably didn't understand something.

**My Service**

```
angular.module('tvc.Services.Xml', []);
angular.module('tvc.Services.Xml')
    .service('xmlService', ['$http', '$log', '$q', 'x2js', function($http, $log, $q, x2js) {
        return function(file) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                    parsedFile = {};
            $http
                .get(file).success(function(data) {
                    parsedFile.fileContent = data;
                    parsedFile.json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                    deferred.resolve(parsedFile);
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    $log.warn('Unable to load: ' + file);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
    }]);
```

`console.log(parsedFile);` returns:

```
{
  fileContent: '<xml>...</xml>',
  json: {..},
  __prototype__: {...}
}
```

**My Controller**

```
.controller('KeyaccountsController', ['$scope', 'xmlService', function($scope, xmlService) {

    $scope.keyaccounts = {};

    xmlService('assets/xml/ops_merge_data2.xml').then(function(data) {
        $scope.keyaccounts = data;
    });
    console.log($scope.keyaccounts);
}]);
```

`console.log($scope.keyaccounts);` returns:

```
{}
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous, return the `$http` promise instead

Answer (score 0):

Since the `$http.get()` is asynchronous, the return is happening before the `success` happens, and thus `parsedFile` is undefined.

You either need to return the promise (i.e., `return $http.get(file)` and then do all of the logic that you're doing in your controller, or use the angular `$q` service, like this:

```
angular.module('tvc.Services.Xml', []);
angular.module('tvc.Services.Xml')
.service('xmlService', ['$http', '$log', 'x2js', '$q', function($http, $log, x2js, $q) {
    return function(file) {
        var deferred = $q.defer(); 

        var parsedFile = {};
        $http
            .get(file).success(function(data) {
                parsedFile.fileContent = data;
                parsedFile.json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                deferred.resolve(parsedFile)
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                $log.warn('Unable to load: ' + file);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
}]);
```

And then your controller would be like:

```
.controller('KeyaccountsController', ['$scope', 'xmlService', function($scope, xmlService) {
    xmlService('assets/xml/ops_merge_data2.xml').then(function(data) {
        $scope.keyaccounts = data;
        console.log($scope.keyaccounts);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read the Angular API about $q but I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. However, I updated my post with the new code, maybe you can see my mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I should've put that `console.log($scope.keyaccounts)` inside of the `.then()` -- it is currently being called before the asynchronous call is complete.  See above controller change

Comment: Well, of course it works inside `.then()` but I need it outside of it for my template.

Comment: When you set `$scope.keyaccounts = data` inside of the `.then()` it will trigger an angular `$digest` cycle and update your view.  If it doesn't, post a simple but working jsBin or jsFiddle of your code and we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tevujiwota/1/edit?html,js,output) .  I replaced the `$http` call with setTimeout to simulate waiting on an async call, you would leave the `$http` instead.  Notice the output is empty until the async call is complete, and then it is populated (after 3 seconds, in this case)

Comment: This is my [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/geqakedoti/2/edit?html,js,output). Its exactly like this.

Comment: Okay, what's the issue?  I see`[{foo:bar}]` is resolved and displayed in the view?

Comment: Yes but only until I replace it with the $http request (on my project, not in the jsBin of course). When I use the `$http`, the data gets resolved but its only available inside of `.then()` and thus I can't access it in my view template.

Comment: Then there is something you're not telling us.  [Here](http://jsbin.com/pocagucilo/1/edit?html,js,output), I've added a call to some random github endpoint and you can see it works.  I had to comment out `parsedFile.json = x2js.xml_str2json(data)` because `x2js` is `undefined` - perhaps you're having the same issue?

Comment: If there is something missing you need to know, please tell me. But this is literally everything. I also removed the x2js now and tried a normal `.json` file. Didnt work either. This project is a very small one, nothing big, just basic stuff.

Comment: I have no idea what could be wrong, then... my last response has a working `$http` GET request and literally the only thing I changed from your code to mine is the URL which is being hit (and I removed `x2js` because I don't have that reference.